# How to use VGG19 in Flux.jl?

Tags: julia, flux.jl, flux-machine-learning

I have a specific computer vision problem that I want to try solving using some pre-trained models. The Flux.jl docs don't actually have any pre-trained models in them like some of the other ML frameworks (PyTorch as an example). How would I access those sort of pertained models in Flux?

Comment: If there is something unclear in the Flux.jl documentation that you would like to see changed, can you [file an issue](https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/issues) with the project or [issue a pull request](https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/pulls)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Flux ecosystem, the functionality for something like pre-trained computer vision models has been extrapolated out into a separate package called MetalHead.jl: https://github.com/FluxML/Metalhead.jl

Per the docs there, you can create a VGG19 model by doing:

```
julia> vgg19 = VGG19()
VGG19()
```

and then you can pass the model to something like the `classify` function along with an input image for a validation test.